# Access array var name using dynamic value

Tags: php, arrays

Im not even sure this is possible, but i am wanting to specify a variable array i want to use, using a config file, and depending on that value i can then access that array. The following is a mock up to show what I'm trying to achieve. When i use var_dump it detects its an array but i can't see to get any values from it.

```
    $useArray = "$value1";

    $value1 = array("Claire","18");
    $value2 = array("Sarah","21");

    var_dump($useArray);
    print_r($useArray);
```

Comment: Remove the double quotes from `$useArray = "$value1";`, should just be `$useArray = $value1;`

Comment: What do you exactly want? Do you want to put `$value1` Array into `$userArray` ?

Comment: Questions: Do you want to configurate the name of the used variable? Then wgh000-answer is right, if you want a reference `$useArray points to $value1` then take answer from WasteD. But do `$useArray = &$value1;` for real reference. Else close this question. thnx

Comment: wgh000 answer is what i was looking to achieve thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your config file has the following value

```
$useArray = 'value1';
```

You can then retrive the values set into the arrays

```
$value1 = array("Claire","18");
$value2 = array("Sarah","21");
```

Using

```
var_dump(${$useArray});
```

If the $value1 or $value2 are config arrays, you can store your values into a new config array that you can use elsewhere

```
$config = ${$useArray};
```

Comment: Best answer so far, dont understand the downvote, maybe explain a little more.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, although I don't entirely understand what you are trying to do:

```
$useArray = $value1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the array first before you insert it into the var.

```
$value1 = array("Claire","18");
```

And now insert it:

```
$useArray = $value1;
```

Hope I understood your question right...